# Spring - Inject fields to bean before it gets @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

In Spring, is there a mechanism or listener to detect when a bean annotated with a specific annotation is getting `@Autowired` and run some custom logic on it? Something similar to what `@ConfigurationProperties` already does that automatically injects fields before it gets autowired.

I have a requirement in which I need to inject values to fields of certain beans annotated with `@ExampleAnnotation` before they get instantiated. Ideally, in this listener, I would:

1. Ask if current bean being instantiated is annotated with `@ExampleAnnotation`
2. If it isn't, return. If it is, I'd use reflection to get the names of the fields from this bean and populate them using a repository.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive it with the following code:

```
@Component
class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      // Every spring bean will visit here

      // Check for superclasses or interfaces
      if (bean instanceof MyBean) {
        // do your custom logic here
        bean.setXyz(abc);
        return bean;
      }
      // Or check for annotation using applicationContext
      MyAnnotation myAnnotation = this.applicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName, MyAnnotation.class);
      if (myAnnotation != null) {
        // do your custom logic here
        bean.setXyz(myAnnotation.getAbc());
        return bean;
      }
      return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
      this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    // Optional part. If you want to use Autowired inside BeanPostProcessors 
    // you can use Lazy annotation. Otherwise they may skip bean processing
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    public MyBeanPostProcessor(MyLazyAutowiredBean myLazyAutowiredBean) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, however, `this.applicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName, MyAnnotation.class);` causes all sorts of trouble during build. The stacktrace is too large to put it here but it's related to `Cannot create inner bean...` and dependencies not satisfied. Does `findAnnotationOnBean` have any side effects that could be causing that to happen? When I comment that line, the project builds correctly.

Comment: It works for me. You dont have to use application context to find annotations on classes. There are other utility classes such as `org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils`.

Comment: Probably caused by some magic from Spring Data JPA. I used `getClass().getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)` instead and it works. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess if it's similar to `ConfigurationProperties`, then the class `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` that binds properties to beans may serve as an example. It implements [`BeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) and does the binding in the `postProcessBeforeInitialization` method. This method has the following Javadocs:

"*Apply this BeanPostProcessor to the given new bean instance before any beaninitialization callbacks (like InitializingBean's afterPropertiesSetor a custom init-method). The bean will already be populated with property values.The returned bean instance may be a wrapper around the original.*"

Comment: How does Spring know to run `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` whenever it encounters a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: The `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` will examine the bean to see if it is annotated with `ConfigurationProperties`. If yes it does the binding. As for how it is registered, the Javadoc of `BeanPostProcessor` says that _"an `ApplicationContext` can autodetect `BeanPostProcessor` beans in its bean definitions and apply those post-processors to any beans subsequently created"_. It can also be registered by using the `EnableConfigurationProperties`. [This tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) shows an example.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to write a custom setter and annotate it with @Autowired, like this:

```
@Autowired
public void setExample(Example example)
{

    // Do your stuff here.

    this.example = example;
}
```

However, I don't recommend this practice of modifying a bean before autowiring since it can lead to poor code mantainability and it may be counter-intuitive for other people that need to work on your code too.